# Dropwizard auth filter @permitall annotation does not work on class level

Tags: java, dropwizard

Using Dropwizard 0.9.1 I have created a custom AuthFilter to check session cookie as below:

```
Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SessionAuthFilter extends AuthFilter<String /*session key*/, SessionUser /*principal*/> {

  private SessionAuthFilter() {

  }

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
Cookie sessionKey = requestContext.getCookies().get("sessionKey");
if (sessionKey != null) {
  try {
    Optional<SessionUser> principal = new SessionAuthenticator().authenticate(sessionKey.getValue());
    requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
      @Override
      public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return principal.get();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isSecure() {
        return requestContext.getSecurityContext().isSecure();
      }

      @Override
      public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return SecurityContext.FORM_AUTH;
      }
    });
    return;
  } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
throw new NotAuthorizedException("Please log in!", "realm="+realm);
}
```

And registered it as below:

```
environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new SessionAuthFilter.Builder().setAuthenticator(new
    SessionAuthenticator()).setRealm("Login").buildAuthFilter()));
environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
```

The problem is I can not use @Permitall annotation on class level in Resource classes. It works fine If I use on method, but not filtering on class.

Resource class:

```
@Path("/")
@PermitAll //Doesn't work here
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HomeResource {

  @GET
  @PermitAll //Works fine if here
  @Path("/about")
  public Response get() {
  }
```

}

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authz annotations at the class level is not supported in DW 9.x. You can see in the source code of [`AuthDynamicFeature`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.9.1/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthDynamicFeature.java#L27), only method level annotations are checked, ultimately only registering the auth filter to methods with the Authz annotations.

This limitiation has been fixed in [this pull request (to 1.0.0)](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/1437), where `@RolesAllowed` and `@PermitAll` at the class level will be supported.